# Unable to install Bitcoin Core on my MacOS High Sierra

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, installation

I'm trying to install Bitcoin Core (downloaded from [bitcoin.org/en/download](https://bitcoin.org/en/download)) on my MacOS High Sierra. But, I'm repeatedly getting the error `The document "Bitcoin-Core" could not be opened. Finder cannot open files in the "volume" format.`

[image: The document "Bitcoin-Core" could not be opened. Finder cannot open files in the "volume" format.]

Tried to google about it. But, didn't get any information about this error. Need some help to install this on my machine.

Currently using MacOS High Sierra(10.13.6).

Answer (score 1):

Dammit, what was happening I don't know as a bit new to this MacOS thing. But, rather than double clicking on that stupid drive icon of "Bitcoin-Core" in desktop... I clicked on the drive icon from left-hand side pan from "Devices" section on Finder window & it opened without any error. It's working fine now. Problem fixes guys. What a waste of time. -.-

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't your fault, it's a bug caused by an invalid `.DS_Store` metadata file: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/14414